# Model Choice Field - get the id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am busy trying to get the id only in integer format preferably for the ModelChoiceField. I get the list to display but get's returned in a string format. Please helping me in retrieving the id of ModelChoiceField. I think I need to do this in the view.

```
forms.py
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    items = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Project.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['items']

models.py
class Project(models.Model):
    items = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)

views.py
def ProjectView(request):
    form = ProjectForm(request.POST)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            save_it = form.save(commit=False)
            save_it.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')       
    else:
        form = ProjectForm()

return render(request, 't.html', {'form': form })
```

Comment: I don't understand what problem you're trying to solve here.. What list displays where? what is returned in a string format?

Comment: Can you please tell us what you are trying to do here, because your models and your form don't make sense.

Comment: A dropdown list of a list of Projects gets displayed in the items variable. I am trying to get the id of queryset=Project.objects.all() and send it to the model.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, `items` should never be an `IntegerField`. Your usage has it set up to be a `ForeignKey` to a `Project` so you should just make that explicit

```
items = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

Possibly with a better descriptive name than items.

Then, you don't need to define anything on the form, it just becomes a standard model form, with a standard model form usage.

Comment: Okay, thanks. This is what I tried initially and it worked. But let's say I will use the Project as a Lookup Table for several variables in the Project Model? Then the Lookup Table will not work.

Comment: @CodingBear - That doesn't make any sense... It sounds like you need to rethink about your actual usage and how your models facilitate that.

Comment: Thanks @Sayse. How would I go about implementing a lookup table then?